# Google Sheets: Searching List for Most Recent Passed Value as Sum Increases

Tags: excel, google-sheets

my family and I are doing a challenge to run the distance from one city where my siblings live to another. We have a google form set up in order to log our runs and distance, and then I put in a simple sum formula to show our current total progress. However, I would like to add in a feature on the spreadsheet to show our current location on the "run".

I was able to come up with a list of the cities we would pass through along with the distance to those cities, however I would like the sheet to update to indicate Current Location: "city" when we pass through one of them.

Ideally, this would mean I could input a formula that searches the list of cities (in a second sheet tab), and then identifies when the sum surpasses one of the listed distances, and then returns the names of that most recent surpassed city. I have a copy of the sheet below.

[Copy of sheet (personal data removed)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ubyYO4pHrFDF8HmDMqzH7k98OXNKcfBrRQTzEqG0RKQ/edit?usp=sharing)

I've tried something along the lines of `=INDEX(G:G,MATCH("zzzz",G:G))` for inserting the cities manually as we pass them in column G, but I would need to be constantly updating the sheet on my own in that case. I would be putting the formula in H1 of the form tab.

Hoping this is possible, appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In H2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,VLOOKUP(SUMIF(ROW(E2:E),"<="&ROW(E2:E),E2:E),{Cities!B:B,Cities!A:A},2,TRUE)))`

The first `IF` test leaves the Col-H row blank if the corresponding row in Col E is blank.

`SUMIF` returns the sum up to the current row at each row in Col E.

`VLOOKUP` looks up each of those progressive sums within a virtual array of the data from your 'Cities' sheet in reversed order and returns the second virtual column (which turns out to be your city name). Because all values in Cities!B:B are in perfect ascending order, the final parameter of `VLOOKUP` can be set to `TRUE`, which will return the closest value before the searched value if an exact match is not found.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Please take a moment to choose one of the answers provided and click the check mark next to that post to mark it as "Best Answer." This will let other people here know that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can use `index match cities` and `sum running sheet` with fixed first row to achieve your outcome, here is my solution:

```
=index(Cities!A:B, match(sum($D$2:D2),Cities!B:B,1),1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Accept the answer if helping, thank you :)